# Aws Appsync Graphql api filtering not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, graphql, aws-appsync

I am working on a react native application for which I am using aws appsync graphql subscriptions for real time notifications, My intention is to subscribe and filter notifications for each individual user using a unique identifier, So if a user has ID for example 12345, the code aims to subscribe and receive only those notifications which were sent to user 12345. The problem is that when i used the hardcoded value "12345" for the filter argument, i receive the notification but when i set it dynamically, using a variable that is set in a useEffect function, it does not work, even though debugging on the aws appsync console shows the subscription working fine.

Below is the code and models i am using,

this is the schema for the notification

```
type Notification @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: private }]) {
  id: ID!
  notificationType: String
  senderUserID: String
  senderUserName: String
  senderEmail: String
  sendToID: String
  sendToEmail: String
  createdAt: String
}
```

This is the subscription object autogenerated by aws amplify

```
export const onCreateNotification = /* GraphQL */ `
  subscription OnCreateNotification(
    $filter: ModelSubscriptionNotificationFilterInput
    $owner: String
  ) {
    onCreateNotification(filter: $filter, owner: $owner) {
      id
      notificationType
      senderUserID
      senderUserName
      senderEmail
      sendToID
      sendToEmail
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      owner
    }
  }
`;
```

this is the react native code that i am using, when i use the singlefilterHarcoded object, it works, but i use the singlefilter object , the userid object is set inside a useEffect() function, now you may ask that what if the userid is not set, but i am also debugging this subscription on the cloud console of aws app sync and there the i am seeing the subscription working fine, its just that i do not receive the subscription event on the app.

```
useEffect(() => { 
  
    const singlefilter = {
        sendToID: { eq: userid }         
    }

    const singlefilterHardcoded = {
        sendToID: { eq: "6d2ac700-a80f-4e96-ad0a-05403bf734f7" }         
    }

    const subscription = API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(onCreateNotification, { filter : singlefilter})
    ).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
        console.log('received subscribtion data')
        console.log(data)
        if (data && data.value && data.value.data.onCreateNotification) {
            alert('you have received a new friend request')
            // value below gives information about the notification contents
            console.log(data.value.data.onCreateNotification)
        }
        
        },
        error: (error) => console.log(error["error"])
    });

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    }, [])
```

Can someone please explain why it works when i use a hardcoded string but not the userid even though they have the same exact value. any help would be massively appreciated. thank you